# Missing grid shift files for cs2cs.exe?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, windows, cs2cs

I'm trying to convert a coordinate to WGS84 degrees to NAD27 UTM on windows (vista 32 home basic), from python.

I tried installing pyproj with no luck even after researching for a while; so decided it would be easier to install the proj windows executables straight from the source [(osgeo.org)](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) - specifically the link for proj446_win32_bin.zip under 'Binaries' - then just invoke them from python and read the return value in to python.  Speed is not important in this application.

(maybe cs2cs.exe is not the quickest way?  If there's a different recommendation I'm all ears!)

I see in the docs where it says the files in proj-datumgrid-1.5.zip should be added to the nad dir before configuring and installing, but, since this was a download of precompiled binaries there was no install procedure (unless I missed something?)

Also I'm not sure what to do with this line in the FAQ, since these were existing binaries:

> On Windows the extra nadshift target must be used. For instance nmake
>   /f makefile.vc nadshift in the proj/src directory.

Anyway, trying the 'trivial' datum shift example in the [proj FAQ](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/FAQ):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Tom>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\proj\bin

C:\Users\Tom>cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=NAD27 +to +proj=latlong +datum=NAD83<enter>
-117 30<enter>
*       * 0.000
<enter again, for good measure>
0dE     0dN 0.000
^Z
```

Trying it with the -v switch as recommended in the proj FAQ:

```
C:\Users\Tom>cs2cs -v +proj=latlong +datum=NAD27 +to +proj=latlong +datum=NAD83<enter>
# ---- From Coordinate System ----
#Lat/long (Geodetic)
#
# +proj=latlong +datum=NAD27 +ellps=clrk66 +nadgrids=conus,ntv1_can.dat
# ---- To Coordinate System ----
#Lat/long (Geodetic)
#
# +proj=latlong +datum=NAD83 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
-117 30<enter>
*       * 0.000
<enter again>
0dE     0dN 0.000
^Z
```

Also trying with PROJ_DEBUG env var also as recommended in the FAQ:

```
C:\Users\Tom>set PROJ_DEBUG=1

C:\Users\Tom>cs2cs -v +proj=latlong +datum=NAD27 +to +proj=latlong +datum=NAD83
pj_open_lib(proj_def.dat): call fopen(C:/PROJ/NAD/proj_def.dat) - failed
pj_open_lib(proj_def.dat): call fopen(C:/PROJ/NAD/proj_def.dat) - failed
# ---- From Coordinate System ----
#Lat/long (Geodetic)
#
# +proj=latlong +datum=NAD27 +ellps=clrk66 +nadgrids=conus,ntv1_can.dat
# ---- To Coordinate System ----
#Lat/long (Geodetic)
#
# +proj=latlong +datum=NAD83 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
-117 30
pj_open_lib(conus): call fopen(C:/PROJ/NAD/conus) - failed
*       * 0.000

0dE     0dN 0.000
^Z
```

That one was a bit more informative.  Looking in C:/proj/nad, I see conus.lla but not 'conus', and I do not see proj_def.dat.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have some reason that prevents to use the GDAL Windows binaries from gisinternals.com/sdk? At least they seem to contain all necessary `cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=NAD27 +to +proj=latlong +datum=NAD83
-117 30
117d0'2.901"W   30d0'0.407"N 0.000`

Comment: I have not tried those.  Installing now...

Comment: I must still be missing something obvious - after installing and adding the bin dir to the path: cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=NAD27 +to +proj=latlong +datum=NAD83<enter>-117 30<enter> shows this: 117dW   30dN 0.000  (which is definitely better than before!)

Comment: If you use the zip version run sdkshell.bat for opening the command window. It should set the environment right.

Comment: Hey that works, thanks for the help.  So, do you see this as the easiest solution to accomplish the goal, or, do you know of a cleaner easier way to integrate this functionality into python?

Comment: I asked a rephrasing of this question, and referenced this question and your answer, here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131888

Comment: I believe that your main problem is that your PROJ_LIB environment is set somehow wrong. I found two OSGeo4W installations from my computers and one finds the grid shift file, the other not. The one that works has `PROJ_LIB=C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\\share\proj`

Comment: Actually that PROJ_LIB path is odd with double \\. I could repair my failing OSGeo4W installation by editing it into `PROJ_LIB=C:\Program Files(x86)\QGIS Brighton\share\proj`.